# Querying parents from adjacency list in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I have the following table stored in a sqlite database, it represents an adjacency list. And i want to make fetch all parents for a given id 4 levels deep. The datatabase is considerably long and if anyone needs some values of it I can edit this question and post it.

## The code

```
class TreeNode(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'tree'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(id))
    name = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
    parent = relationship("TreeNode", remote_side=id)


    def __repr__(self):
        return "TreeNode(name=%r, id=%r, parent_id=%r)" % (
                    self.name,
                    self.id,
                    self.parent_id
                )


# function that query all parents of a given id 4 levels deep
def print_tree_from_code(series_code):

    node = (
                 session.query(TreeNode)
                 .options(
                        joinedload("parent", "parent", 'parent', 'parent') # XXX: Is this the best way to
                                                                           # make a 4 level deep query?

                  )
                 .filter(TreeNode.id == series_code) 
                 .first()
             )

    print(node)
```

## Output

When i call the function `print_tree_from_code(3)` The query only returns a single node!:

```
TreeNode(name='Time deposits', id=5, parent_id=3)
```

Anyone has any idea of what am i doing wrong with my code? Advices/Tips are more than welcome.

Comment: Have you tried calling `all()` instead of `first()` in the query?

Comment: Yes, still only one result